# MFC: How can we switch from CTreeCtrl to CTreeView easly?

Tags: c++, mfc, csplitterwnd

I have an graphics MFC application which historically was developed by using a `CTreeCtrl`.
I want to add a `CSplitterWnd` to improve its graphical interface. However, I found that the CTreeCtrl is not compatible with CSplitterWnd. Apparently i must use a `CTreeView`.

```
CSplitterWnd m_wndSplitter;
// Runtime error on CreateView
m_wndSplitter.CreateView(0,0,RUNTIME_CLASS(myCTreeCtrl),CSize(100,100),pContext))
```

**My problem:**
If I switch to `CTreeView`, i must develop a lot of functions (example: SelectItem)

**Question:**
How can I switch easly from `CTreeCtrl` to `CTreeView` ? 
or can I for example insert a `ctreectrl` in a `CFormview` which will be used instead of `CtreeView`?

Comment: I think you are on the wrong path here. Also I think you can add ctreectrl to splitter if you really want to and done right. To improve the UI try to play with the template projects.

Comment: @darune ok, thanks.  I will insist more on the use of `CTreeCtrl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CTreeView` class has member function `CTreeCtrl& GetTreeCtrl() const`. Replace all occurrences of

```
SelectItem(foo);
```

by

```
GetTreeCtrl().SelectItem(foo);
```